# Asking a question with "have" without do-support: "What symptoms has Anne?"

Tags: grammaticality, questions, do-support

The context is that a doctor is asking about somebody's child's symptoms of influenza.

Is this question correct: "What symptoms has Anne?" If it's incorrect, then why?

It looks strange to me, I would rather ask "What symptoms does Anne have?" but don't know why.

Comment: [This article](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2011/05/do-you-havehave-youhave-you-got.html) might be helpful.

Comment: There are two verbs _have_. One means 'possess' and the other is an auxiliary verb for the perfect construction. The auxiliary _have_ inverts in a question when it's the first auxiliary (_Have you considered chartered accountancy?_), and in the UK, so does the 'possess' _have_ (_Have you any questions?_), but in the US the 'possess' _have_ is not treated like an auxiliary, but undergoes _Do_-Support (_Do you have any questions?_), like any other meaningful verb (_Do you like mayonnaise?_). So in US English, _have_ is a semi-auxiliary; in the UK, it's an auxiliary.

Comment: @JohnLawler: though I have been watching non-auxiliary _have_ worm its way into British life over the last fifty years. I even find myself saying _Do you have_ sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Lawler says in a comment, this use is possible in British English. But even in Britain, it is rather old-fashioned or literary. The normal British form would be

> What symptoms has Anne got?

Comment: Pretty common in the US, too.

Comment: @JohnLawler -- I think of "have got" as a Briticism.  I think most Americans would say "What symptoms does Anne have?"

Comment: The _have/has_ is normally contracted lost unless it's been moved, as in a question. _What's she got? Anne's got symptoms of leprosy and tuberculosis_. Note that _What's she got?_ is pronounced /wətʃi'gat/, exactly the same as _What she got_.

Comment: But a hundred years ago, even in the U.S. one would have asked "What symptoms has Anne?" See [this Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Have+you+any%2CDo+you+have+any%2CHave+you+got+any&year_start=1800&year_end=2007&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: Thanks, I see it's different in British and American English... Is there an "International" version in this case?

Comment: US/American English is also called "International English".

Comment: @camcam When in Rome, ... (although people in the US were not in the least fazed by my Britishisms. Until I asked where the cordials were in a supermarket.)